# What are the differences between the those ways of using the SSH -Agent?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, ssh

I have a question about the different ways, meanings, and errors using the SSH-Agent.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in Amazon Web Services.

What are the differences between the different ways of using the SSH -Agent?

This is the first one:

```
eval 'ssh-agent -s'
ssh-add id_rsa
```

To check if this step function I use the command `ssh localhost` to check if the connection does not ask me for the passphrase.

However, other times that I used this command we obtained a refused connection or the connection asked us for the passphrase. Then, to resolve this problem, I found another way:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent)"
ssh-add id_rsa
```

Nevertheless, sometimes we obtained again a refused connection or the connection ask us for the passphrase but I found a third way to resolve the problem:

```
exec ssh-agent bash
ssh-add id_rsa
```

The problem is that I do not understand the reason, because sometimes I have to use one or other - with the same distro (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) in the same service (AWS). What's the difference between them?

Comment: Does this exist in a broader context? If you're always running `ssh-add` anyway why do the check? For an explanation of `eval` check the man page or [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23111/what-is-the-eval-command-in-bash) question. The second example would execute whatever is returned by ssh-agent instead of getting the return value of `ssh-agent`. For the last one check the man page of `exec`.

Comment: I do the check to check that always function correctly, because, if the ssh-add didn't add correctly the key, then, the program (Hadoop) won't work. This is why that if the check didn't work I have to do one of the next ways to setup Hadoop correctly.

Comment: You're running those commands manually and check the output or do you have an actual script that does contain logic to do the check? If yo do it manually shouldn't the difference be apparent by the kind of output that's generated? Most likely there is some other misconfiguration happening on your end. Did you read the man page for `ssh-agent` it does have an explanation for the `-s` way.

Comment: Manually.

I put the lines that I've written above. Basically, the problem is that I've always used the same distro, with the same configuration and the same steps, but sometimes the first one option didn't work. the first time that it happened I found the second solution, and other time that the second solution didn't work I found the third solution. However, the different posts (some from stackoverflow) never explained the problems because you have to use another different command to do the same in case that the first one fails.

Comment: Yes, I have read and it said: '-s: Generate Bourne shell commands on stdout.  This is the default if SHELL does not look like it's a csh style of shell.'. I am not a master in Linux, but I supposed that you can use different bash or style to execute the programs, maybe?

Comment: Did you ever try to run `ssh-agent` straight up and try to make sense of the output? `ssh-agent` acts as a "proxy" to your keys. You need to provide the passphrase once after you run `ssh-add`. Those commands use different ways to let other programs use the agent. Essentially you only run the agent once at the start of a new session and add your key(s) once.

Comment: A connection refused usually means there is no service running on that port. Did you follow the [user guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html) and made sure the instance you're trying to connect to passed all Status Checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 rules to begin with:

- Unless you explicitly use TCSH or the like, you'll be using Bash, so the `-s` argument is redundant.
- In Bash, `eval` does not care about the quoting level, meaning that `eval "1 2"` and `eval 1 2` will do exactly the same thing. However, the quotes still change the interpretation of the characters inside:

  ```
  print_args () { while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do echo "$1"; shift; done; }
  eval "print_args 1 '2 3' 4"   # prints "1", "2 3", "4"
  eval print_args 1 '2 3' 4     # prints "1", "2", "3", "4"
  ```

With these in mind, here's what these do:

```
eval 'ssh-agent'
eval ssh-agent
```

With either of these, the string `ssh-agent` is parsed by your shell (Bash) into the command `ssh-agent`, and executed. This command starts `ssh-agent` in the background, and prints some settings to stdout, such as `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=...`. However, these settings are *not* interpreted by your shell, which in turn means the shell won't know how to contact the agent. In fact, the `ssh-add` command will probably produce the error: `Error connecting to agent: Connection refused`. For this reason, this command is *never* useful. Perhaps you meant to replace the single quotes `'` with back quotes? (Unfortunately I don't know how to get back quotes to show up in inline code snippets here.) If so read on.

```
eval "$(ssh-agent)"
eval $(ssh-agent)
eval "`ssh-agent`"
eval `ssh-agent`
```

With any of these, Bash first performs *command substitution*. So, it runs `ssh-agent`, this starts the program `ssh-agent` in the background, and outputs settings like `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=...`. Now the substitution kicks in, so Bash replaces `$(ssh-agent)` by its output `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=...`. Second, the `eval` is run, but now on those intermediate commands: `eval SSH_AUTH_SOCK=...`. This way, the settings output by `ssh-agent` are imported into the running shell, so `ssh-add` will know how to find the `ssh-agent` process. Usually, this is what you want to do.

```
exec ssh-agent bash
```

This replaces you current shell by one where the settings output by `ssh-agent` are already incorporated. However, this destroys any other shell customizations, because the new shell won't have them. This is an ok way to add the settings from `ssh-agent`, but only when you don't care about your current shell.

With all these said, there should be no difference in how subsequent `ssh user@server` commands work between options 2 and 3. Whatever differences you're seeing ("sometimes") are not due to `ssh-agent` or the shell settings, but rather, to network conditions.

As an aside, to tell `ssh` to connect without attempting to use password authentication, try one of:

```
ssh user@server -o BatchMode=true
ssh user@server -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey
```